# Parsing multiple pipe delimited columns into rows while retaining appropriate alignment and ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm being forced to worth with data that is presented with a unique ID, and a number of columns.  Some of these columns themselves contain additional detail about 'sub' records, and these are pipe delimited fields.

I'm presenting a modified/generic table that contains similar pipe delimited fields that I am dealing with.  The idea here is that each sub-item within column aligns with the same sub-item in subsequent columns.  I.e. there will always be the same number of sub-items in each column per unique ID, but each row can contain a different number of sub-items.

[image]

While I can parse the data using XML and some CTEs, I'm not confident values will always present themselves in the final query as they're input in the original table, and this feels like a hack more than a good solution.  Especially considering the actual table I'm dealing with has thousands of rows.  I'm hoping someone out there has a more elegant solution.

```
DECLARE @Inputs TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Generic1 VARCHAR(50),
    Generic2 VARCHAR(50),
    Generic3 VARCHAR(50)
)

Insert into @Inputs
VALUES
(1,'yes|no|yes|no','12345.54|34343.34|0|3453.22','a|b|c|d'),
(2,'no|yes','54321.12|12345.12','b|d'),
(3, 'yes|yes|yes','12345.12|78907.32|65432.21','e|f|g|h')

select * from @Inputs

;WITH
cGeneric1 AS (
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by ID order by ID) as RowID, 
        ID, 
        rtrim(ltrim(n.r.value('.', 'varchar(200)'))) Generic1
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            Generic1
        FROM @Inputs
        ) as T
      CROSS APPLY (select cast('<r>'+replace(Generic1,'|', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as S(XMLCol)
      CROSS APPLY S.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r)),

cGeneric2 AS (
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by ID order by ID) as RowID, 
        ID, 
        TRY_PARSE(rtrim(ltrim(n.r.value('.', 'varchar(200)'))) as numeric(10,2)) Generic2
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            Generic2
        FROM @Inputs
        ) as T
      CROSS APPLY (select cast('<r>'+replace(Generic2,'|', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as S(XMLCol)
      CROSS APPLY S.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r)),

cGeneric3 AS (
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by ID order by ID) as RowID, 
        ID, 
        rtrim(ltrim(n.r.value('.', 'varchar(200)'))) Generic3
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            Generic3
        FROM @Inputs
        ) as T
      CROSS APPLY (select cast('<r>'+replace(Generic3,'|', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as S(XMLCol)
      CROSS APPLY S.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r))



SELECT
    G1.ID,
    G1.Generic1,
    G2.Generic2,
    G3.Generic3
FROM cGeneric1 G1
  INNER JOIN cGeneric2 G2
    ON G2.ID=G1.ID
      AND G2.RowID=G1.RowID
  INNER JOIN cGeneric3 G3
    ON G3.ID=G1.ID
      AND G3.RowID=G1.RowID
```

Comment: Do any of these columns ever have more than 4 delimited sub-values in them?

Comment: Can CLR solution be suitable for you?

Comment: @TabAlleman, yes, this is possible.  Likely fewer than 7.

Comment: @JohnyL, It is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a parse/split function that returns the sequence

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Generic1 varchar(50),Generic2 varchar(50),Generic3 varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Yes|No|Yes|No','12345.54|3443.34|0|3453.22','a|b|c|d'),
(2,'Yes|No','54321.12|12345.12','b|d')


Select A.ID 
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select B1.RetSeq
                      ,Generic1 = B1.RetVal
                      ,Generic2 = B2.RetVal
                      ,Generic3 = B3.RetVal
                  From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](Generic1,'|') B1
                  Join [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](Generic2,'|') B2 on B1.RetSeq=B2.RetSeq
                  Join [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](Generic3,'|') B3 on B1.RetSeq=B3.RetSeq
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  Generic1    Generic2    Generic3
1   1       Yes         12345.54    a
1   2       No          3443.34     b
1   3       Yes         0           c
1   4       No          3453.22     d
2   1       Yes         54321.12    b
2   2       No          12345.12    d
```

**The Function if Interested.**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if the columns always held four or fewer sub-values, you could use the built-in `PARSENAME` function.   But even though they can hold more than 4, you can always write your own `PARSENAME`.

Write a function that gets passed a string value and an integer (and optionally a delimiter character, or you could just hard-code it to be the pipe character).   The function would use `CHARINDEX` to start with a certain occurrence* of the delimiter character (or the beginning of the string), and find the next occurrence of the delimiter character (or the end of the string) and return the substring between those character positions.

*"certain occurrence" is specified by the integer parameter of the function.

So in the end, if you called your function like this:  `MyFunction('hello|world|peace',1,'|')`, it would return the string "world" (assuming you used zero-based logic with the integer parameter..."world" being the substring between the first pipe and the second pipe.)

Then you can get substrings from your columns and be sure you get the corresponding ones by using the same integer value in each function call.

I don't know what kind of performance this will have, but it will make the code very readable, and allow you to work with the sub-values "inline" in a larger query (note that it's not clear from your question if this is your ultimate goal or not).